# $route change events vs. $('window').load() in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a directive where I'm dynamically calculating the height of each `li` in an ajax-driven ng-repeater, finding the tallest one, and then setting all sibling `li`'s to have the same height as the tallest.

Each `li` has a nested div with an `img` tag:

```
<li ng-repeat="t in things">
    <div>
        <img>
        <p>some text and stuff</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Because I need the images to be there *before* getting the height, I thought checking for window load made the most sense:

```
angular.module('directives', [])
    .directive('findHeight', ['$window', function ($window) {
        return {
            link: function (scope, el) {
                $window.on('load', function () {
                   // do my thang...
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

And that works... *on load*... But when I change routes and apply this directive to subsequent views it does not fire (because the window has already loaded).

**My Question:** I've researched Angular's [$route events](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route) but there does not seem to be anything for me to react to that involves both the route change *and* window content being loaded when the new route resolves.

So instead of window.load I'm checking for image loading instead. Is there something I'm overlooking within Angular so I don't need to listen for image loading or is this a suitable approach? I guess I'm wondering if Angular has any events built in that I may be overlooking.

```
  angular.module('directives', [])
    .directive('findHeight', function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, el) {
                angular.element('img').on('load', function () {
                   // do my groove thang...
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use this event:

```
$scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function($currentRoute, $previousRoute) {
});
```

rather than $window.on('load',function() {
})

Comment: Thanks. I tried '$routeChangeSuccess' but did not get the result I needed. I'll give it another try in a separate project. I'm wondering if there might be something else going on with my application that is causing my issue.